# How to use browser spell check in tinymce on IE9 and other browser?

Tags: tinymce

In my application i am using tinymce and i want browser spell check functionality on IE9 and other browser.

Please help me how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

Built in spell checking for IE was only included in IE10 onwards.  IE9 will require a spell check add-on to be installed to get this functionality.

To enable the browser spell check in other browsers that do support it you will need to set [browser_spellcheck](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:browser_spellcheck) to true in your configuration

```
tinymce.init({ 
...
browser_spellcheck : true 
});
```

and make sure that `contextmenu` is not included in your plugins list.